# How to escape single quote in Flexdashboard Navbar Menu?

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I'm using R markdown to create a flexdashboard. I'm having difficulty escaping a single quote in the title of one of my navbar menus.

I would like for my menu title to include a single quote and have tried escaping this with `{data-navmenu="The Joneses\' House"}`. If I knit that code, the navbar menu for The Joneses' House does not appear. If I remove the backslash and apostrophe (') and knit, the menu will appear (but with no apostrophe of course).

I've included my code below with YAML. In this code, the menu does not appear in the dashboard. How can I make it so that the menu title includes a single apostrophe? Thank you.

```
---
title: "Sample Dashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

Bedroom {data-navmenu="The Joneses\' House"}
=====================================
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a fix, but it's not an escape.

I believe you will not be able to do anything short of JS to change this. `flexdashboard` uses the navigation tab name as the ID of an HTML element. An HTML element id can't have special characters.

My workaround doesn't seem to want to work with only this sparse bit of code. However, as soon as I added another tab, a bit of R code, or anything else, it works just fine.

I used JQuery to change the nav bar text after you render the page. You can place the `fixit` chunk with `engine='js'` anywhere in your script. Don't forget the space at the end of the string of text `("House ")`. It's part of the steps `flexdashboard` takes when it compiles the page.

The code

#### updated; I apparently lost the dropdown arrow

````
---
title: "Sample Dashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---


Bedroom {data-navmenu='The Joneses House'}
=====================================

More info...



Bath {data-navmenu='The Other House'}
=====================================


```{r fixit, engine="js", results="asis"}

setTimeout(function(){ 
  tx = $('#TheJonesesHouse > a').html();
  tx = tx.replace("Joneses", "Joneses'");
  $('#TheJonesesHouse > a').html(tx);
}, 200); // for loading time

```
````

From the viewer pane (updated):

[image]

From my browser (updated):

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the clever solution, Kat. I added unicode to your code to get the dropdown arrow to appear. However, I'm unsure how to adjust the fontsize of the unicode. Any advice? This is what I've added to your code: ```setTimeout(function(){
  
  $('#TheJonesesHouse > a').text("The Joneses\' House \u23F7");
}, 200); // for loading time```

Comment: Oh, man! I totally missed that. I've modified my answer a bit. You need this arrow tied to an action. It's fixed now!

Comment: @ Kat: Great work! Is it possible to add several tabs under "The Joneses' Hose"? E.g. Bedroom, Kitchen, Basement, etc.?

Comment: Yes! To add "Kitchen" to "The Jones' House", copy the code for the bedroom tab creation. If you want the kitchen to be listed after the bedroom in the dropdown, then paste that copied code any time after the bedroom tab creation. Change the word "Bedroom" to "Kitchen" in the copied code.